# Any restrictions on signing a check over to a third party?

Tags: united-states, check, deposits, endorsement

In the US : Can I endorse a payout check from an IRA (from a well known institution) to another person? The check will be large, over $10,000. He would deposit it in his bank.

Comment: The check will be from an IRA ( Vanguard) not US Treasury; I don't know why it was changed .

Comment: You wrote that it was a check from “IRS”, not “IRA” as you intended. Someone saw that and clarified that a check from the IRS is referred to as a treasury check, and that is the first version I saw. I will delete my answer, revert the question back to its original state, and fix the confusing typo.

Comment: In broad, general, terms 0 you can't do third party cheques anymore.  Those days are gone.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In my limited experience, bank tellers are very cautious these days because check fraud is so common. They are especially cautious when the dollar amounts get up to multiple thousands. I don’t know the circumstances that lead you to ask this question, but everyone might have a much easier time if you simply go to your own bank first and convert it to a cashiers check in the name of your recipient.

Comment: If you don’t have a bank, then if you and the other person go in person to his bank, you should have no trouble depositing it to his account.